# Updating / Deleting JoinTable records with ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models: movies, movie_tags and movie_tag_counts

It is a classic has many through relationship. My use case is that every movie can have multiple tags and user can vote on tags that were already added.

My Problem is that I can't seem to update an existing object in movie_tag_counts

```
movie_tag_count = MovieTagCount.first
movie_tag_count.count += 1
movie_tag_count.save
```

the result is this error message

> TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string

My best guess is that the reason is that movie_tag_counts table doesn't have an id column of its own, but I still have no idea how to fix it.

My current workaround is to execute a sql statement directly

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my guess was right, ActiveRecord expects an id column, I added it like this

```
add_column :movie_tag_counts, :id, :primary_key
```

and everything worked perfectly. I'm sure there's a way to do it without the id column by overwriting some AR methods, but I guess having another column won't hurt that much